# Adjust screen brightness without showing the brightness-adjusted popup using Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, applescript

I am currently working on an app using Python that automatically adjusts the screen brightness in accordance with the contents on the screen (os: macOS Monterey). The only issue I am having is that whenever the brightness is adjusted, there is this usual popup on the screen. It is very distracting and greatly hampers the user experience.

[The "brightness-adjusted" popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWnh1.png)

Here's the code:

```
os.system('osascript -e \'tell application "System Events"\' -e \'key code 145\' -e \' end tell\'') # decrease brightness

os.system('osascript -e \'tell application "System Events"\' -e \'key code 144\' -e \' end tell\'') # increase brightness
```

These lines basically execute AppleScript code on the terminal using the `os.system` method to press the brightness-down and brightness-up keys, respectively.

So my question is, is there any way I can adjust the brightness without showing the brightness-adjusted popup, such that when the users themselves adjust the brightness, the pop-up is shown, but not when the code does the same?

**Edit #1 -**

I tried changing the AppleScript part, as @Mark Setchell suggested

Here's the code:-

```
scpt = '''
    tell application "System Preferences"
        reveal anchor "displaysDisplayTab" of pane "com.apple.preference.displays"
    end tell
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences" to tell window "Built-in Retina Display"
        set value of value indicator 1 of slider 1 of group 2 of tab group 1 to (get (value of value indicator 1 of slider 1 of group 2 of tab group 1) + 0.0625)
    end tell
    quit application "System Preferences"
    '''

p = Popen(['osascript', '-'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate(scpt)
```

But this is giving this error -

`execution error: System Events got an error: Can’t get tab group 1 of process "System Preferences". Invalid index.`

I understand that this code was for an older version of macOS, but I can't seem to find the current alternative for macOS Monterey. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Never tried it but this claims to have a solution... https://www.generacodice.com/en/articolo/3656285/move-the-position-of-or-hide-the-brightness-volume-pop-ups-on-high-sierra

Comment: Did you disable SIP and do the `defaults write...` things? That was the crux of the idea, rather than the Applescript.

Comment: To change the brightness of my display, I like to use a CLI like [this one](https://github.com/nriley/brightness) or [this one](https://github.com/kevva/brightness-cli). They can be called through the `do shell script`-command in Applescript or by just calling shell in Python. When used with Applescript, be sure to include the full path to the executable, which is likely to be `/usr/local/bin/brightness`.